# How to return an array of records in Excel VBA Function?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Consider code below.  How can I return a multidimensional array in the below method?

My SQL Statement returns this:

```
+-----+-------------+
| id  | description |
+-----+-------------+
| 111 | AAA-11      |
| 222 | BBB-2222    |
+-----+-------------+
```

`GetOrder` only returns the first row. I want the array to contain all rows. When I use `GetOrder(i)`, which is how I think I should populate an array, I get an error of "ByRef argument type mismatch".  My return type is `Variant`, which I think should cover Array type.  When I change Function return to be Array, I get another error, which makes me think that is the wrong direction to pursue.

How can I return an array of records without errors?

```
Function GetOrder(OrderNo As Long) As Variant

Const CONN = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver};SERVER=;DATABASE=;UID=;PWD=; OPTION=3"

Const SQL = "select * from items where category_id = ?"

Dim dbConn As ADODB.connection, dbCmd As ADODB.Command
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim param As ADODB.Parameter, n As Long

Set dbConn = New ADODB.connection
dbConn.Open CONN

Set dbCmd = New ADODB.Command
With dbCmd
    .ActiveConnection = dbConn
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .CommandText = SQL
    Set param = .CreateParameter("P1", adInteger, adParamInput, 0)
    .Parameters.Append param
End With

Set rs = dbCmd.Execute(n, OrderNo)

Dim i As Integer
i = 0
Do While Not rs.EOF
   GetOrder = Array(rs(0).Value, rs(1).Value) ' I want GetOrder to be an array of records
   rs.MoveNext
   i = i + 1
Loop
   
dbConn.Close

End Function
```

Comment: You could use the [GetRows method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/getrows-method-ado?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 2):

You are re-creating the `Array` with each iteration of the loop. So the function is returning the last record from the SQL recordset.  Try something like this:

```
Dim results As Variant
Redim results(1 to rs.Recordcount, 1 to rs.Fields.Count)
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
i = 1
Do While Not rs.EOF
    For j = 1 To rs.Fields.Count
        results(i, j) = rs(j - 1).Value
    Next j
    i = i + 1
Loop
dbConn.Close
GetOrder = results
```